# rxjs : zip(...promiseArray.map(from)) -> throws "undefined is not a function (near 'scheduler.schedule...)"

Tags: rxjs

Weird behavior with rxjs. `getPromise` is an async function returning a Promise. When I run this script it will throw an exception `TypeError : undefined is not a function (near 'scheduler.schedule...')`

```
zip(...[getPromise(), getPromise()].map(from)).subscribe(() => {
    console.log('hey');
});
```

But this will work (notice the difference inside `map`):

```
zip(...[getPromise(), getPromise()].map(p => from(p))).subscribe(() => {
    console.log('hey');
});
```

Why the second version works but not the first?

Comment: could you create a runnable version of your issue? I have an idea of what the issue could be but I would imagine you would get an `Error: scheduler.schedule is not a function` error instead of the error you're getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`from` accepts several arguments, `map` of `Array` sends the index of the current element as the 2nd argument.
Therefore `.map(from)` is the same as `.map((value, index, sourceArray) => from(value, index, sourceArray))`. What is wrong.

Comment: I had this thought, but wouldn't passing an index as the second argument give the error `Error: scheduler.schedule is not a function` which is different to the error the OP is getting: `undefined is not a function`?

Comment: `scheduler` is the latest argument. you can call `from(1,2,3,3,4,5, scheduler)` or without it. And I think the problem is that `from` tries to solve promises from the source again, and their internal logic tries to call some function that isn't defined after the very first call of the promise.

Comment: @NickParsons I think satan is right. The exact error is "TypeError : undefined is not a function (near 'scheduler.schedule...')"